# Windows Azure Cloud best practice for localization

Tags: c#-4.0, azure, localization, globalization

I have a MVC Cloud Based project which currently support two culture, Sweden and France

now depending on my client i want the resource file to be created according to his culture

**Now the problem is i dont want to redeploy to Azure cloud and still want to add My resource files dynamically**

is it possible if i copy the Dll for a Particular Culture Directly to Azure using Remote Desktop

i have tried this is my local machine and it failed , but when i compiled my solution the new Dll's added to Bin folders worked for new culture

**what can be the Best approach for cloud based localization where DB hit is a Major issue as it costly**

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to MikeWo's solution you could look at creating a custom **ResourceProviderFactory**. There is [an example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx) that shows you how to create a sample ExternalResourceProviderFactory that can load external assemblies.

You could modify this class and have it download the assemblies from blob storage. After creating the custom ResourceProviderFactory you can simply add it to your web.config, no need to use startup tasks:

```
<globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto"
     resourceProviderFactoryType="CustomResourceProviders.ExternalResourceProviderFactory, CustomResourceProviders, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f201d8942d9dbbb1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking storing the satellite assemblies in BLOB storage and have your application use a background task to go fetch all the assemblies from a specific BLOB container periodically.  You can have a background process on the Web Role wake up and look in the BLOB container, as well as see what satellite assemblies it has in it's bin folder.  If it finds a new assembly (or updated one) in the BLOB container it can pull it down.

I've not worked with satellite assemblies in a long time, so I'm not sure if you can update one that is in use or not, or if you drop new ones in the bin if they just start working immediately.  If such a "hot swappable" approach doesn't work then you can at least use similar logic in a start up task to go get the assemblies from BLOB storage and then just perform an update to the service config (dealing with the RoleEnvrionmentChanging event).  This wouldn't be a full redeploy mind you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use RDP to make changes to your solution. It will not work in the long run.(If anything goes wrong internally Azure has the tenancy to restore the Application with the cspkg it has, in this case your changes done through RDP will not reflect)
You can try putting your resource files in Azure blobs and pick it when you need it.